# Best practice for handling up navigation in fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple activity where I only have a frame in the layout. The activity has 3 fragments:

1. search fields
2. result list
3. details

I create the first fragment `onCreate`, and then use listener pattern to create the other 2 fragments when I need them. I keep track of the current fragment. Everything works like it should.

Currently, to handle up navigation I have the following code in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigateUp() {
    if (currentFragment == detailsFragment) {
        currentFragment = listFragment;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        return true;
    }
    else if (currentFragment == listFragment) {
        currentFragment = searchFragment;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return super.onNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Is the above code the correct way to handle up navigation or is there a better, cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you add your fragment to the activity, you can just add `addToBackStack(null)` and that will cause your back button to pop the fragment to the previous fragment, there would be no need to override this method in that case.

Also if you put the fragment with the  `replace` method it works well, if you put the fragment with `add` method, it may cause a blank screen if no fragment appeared there before

using the `replace` would cause the activity to quit when the last fragment is popped

Comment: The first fragment is not added to the backstack. The other 2 yes. Pressing Back works fine. However, without the above code, pressing up will close the activity and not pop the current fragment.